# sorting integers in order lowest to highest java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, integer

These numbers are stored in the same integer variable. How would I go about sorting the integers in order lowest to highest?

```
11367
11358
11421
11530
11491
11218
11789
```

Comment: In future, you might find it more useful to specify any constraints placed on you. For example, whether you can use provided Java sorting approaches or if you are meant to implement your own. That will help you get more appropriate answer, with less effort :)

Comment: `These numbers are stored in the same integer variable` - I'd expect a Java `int` or `Integer` to have exactly one value at any given point in time: if you want values ordered, use a `Collection` or an _array_.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two options, really:

1. Use standard collections, [as explained by Shakedown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787780/709626)
2. Use [Arrays.sort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)

E.g.,

```
int[] ints = {11367, 11358, 11421, 11530, 11491, 11218, 11789};
Arrays.sort(ints);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(ints));
```

That of course assumes that you already have your integers as an array.
If you need to parse those first, look for [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) and [Integer.parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html).

Comment: FYI - Oracle links do not work. They're either broken or require an Oracle account to view, I can't tell which.

Comment: They seem to have retired 1.4.2... Will update, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can put them into a list and then sort them using their natural ordering, like so:

```
final List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(11367, 11358, 11421, 11530, 11491, 11218, 11789);
Collections.sort( list );
// Use the sorted list
```

If the numbers are stored in the same variable, then you'll have to somehow put them into a `List` and then call `sort`, like so:

```
final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add( myVariable );
// Change myVariable to another number...
list.add( myVariable );
// etc...

Collections.sort( list );
// Use the sorted list
```

- [`Collections.sort( List )`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: Is there a different way to sort the numbers. I have people recommend me about ArrayList but we have to sort with a for loop and an if statement because I never been taught ArrayList yet

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to do it using an algorithm. There are a plethora of sorting algorithms out there. If you aren't concerned too much about efficiency and more about readability and understandability. I recommend Insertion Sort. Here is the psudo code, it is trivial to translate this into java.

```
begin
    for i := 1 to length(A)-1 do
    begin
        value := A[i];
        j := i - 1;
        done := false;
        repeat
            { To sort in descending order simply reverse
              the operator i.e. A[j] < value }
            if A[j] > value then
            begin
                A[j + 1] := A[j];
                j := j - 1;
                if j < 0 then
                    done := true;
            end
            else
                done := true;
        until done;
        A[j + 1] := value;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: the code structure isn't comming out right. Just go here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort

Answer (score 2):

For sorting narrow range of integers try [Counting sort](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/40549/Counting-sort), which has a complexity of `O(range + n)`, where `n` is number of items to be sorted. If you'd like to sort something not discrete use optimal n*log(n) algorithms ([quicksort](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/39552/Quicksort), [heapsort](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/39807/Heapsort), [mergesort](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/39650/Merge-sort)). Merge sort is also used in a method already mentioned by other responses `Arrays.sort`. There is no simple way how to recommend some algorithm or function call, because there are dozens of special cases, where you would use some sort, but not the other.

So please specify the exact purpose of your application (to learn something (well - start with the insertion sort or bubble sort), effectivity for integers (use counting sort), effectivity and reusability for structures (use n*log(n) algorithms), or zou just want it to be somehow sorted - use Arrays.sort :-)). If you'd like to sort string representations of integers, than u might be interrested in radix sort....

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class sortNumber {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Our array contains 13 elements 
    int[] array = {9,  238,  248,  138,  118,  45,  180,  212,  103,  230,  104,  41,  49}; 

    Arrays.sort(array); 

    System.out.printf(" The result : %s", Arrays.toString(array)); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if array.sort doesn't have what your looking for you can try this:

```
package drawFramePackage;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Random;
public class QuicksortAlgorithm {
    ArrayList<AffineTransform> affs;
    ListIterator<AffineTransform> li;
    Integer count, count2;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new QuicksortAlgorithm();
    }
    public QuicksortAlgorithm(){
        count = new Integer(0);
        count2 = new Integer(1);
        affs = new ArrayList<AffineTransform>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 128; i++){
            affs.add(new AffineTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, new Random().nextInt(1024), 0));
        }
        affs = arrangeNumbers(affs);
        printNumbers();
    }
    public ArrayList<AffineTransform> arrangeNumbers(ArrayList<AffineTransform> list){
        while (list.size() > 1 && count != list.size() - 1){
            if (list.get(count2).getTranslateX() > list.get(count).getTranslateX()){
                list.add(count, list.get(count2));
                list.remove(count2 + 1);
            }
            if (count2 == list.size() - 1){
                count++;
                count2 = count + 1;
            }
            else{
            count2++;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    public void printNumbers(){
        li = affs.listIterator();
        while (li.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(li.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take Inputs from User and Insertion Sort. Here is how it works:

```
package com.learning.constructor;

import java.util.Scanner;



public class InsertionSortArray {

public static void main(String[] args) {    

Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("enter number of elements");

int n=s.nextInt();


int arr[]=new int[n];

System.out.println("enter elements");

for(int i=0;i<n;i++){//for reading array
    arr[i]=s.nextInt();

}

System.out.print("Your Array Is: ");
//for(int i: arr){ //for printing array
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    System.out.print(arr[i] + ",");

}
System.out.println("\n");        

    int[] input = arr;
    insertionSort(input);
}

private static void printNumbers(int[] input) {

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(input[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
}

public static void insertionSort(int array[]) {
    int n = array.length;
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
        int key = array[j];
        int i = j-1;
        while ( (i > -1) && ( array [i] > key ) ) {
            array [i+1] = array [i];
            i--;
        }
        array[i+1] = key;
        printNumbers(array);
    }
}

}
```