# Java to sort list of custom object on the basis of string

Tags: java, list, sorting

```
class Person 
 {
 private String name;
 private String profession;
}
```

profession has values:

> - engineer
> - Doctor
> - Teacher
> - student

I have list of person and want to sort it on the basis of Profession.
engineer comes first then Doctor and then Teacher and then student.

Is it possible to sort it with comparable interface.

Comment: What is your sorting logic. I think Engineer>Doctor>Teacher>Student is not possible for `String`

Comment: maybe if profession was an enum...

Comment: there is a default string function which sort according to alphabets

Comment: [You can refer my answer from this question which is somewhat like this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29777696/fastest-way-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-in-java/29778089#29778089

Comment: I vote for `enum` since it can be easily compared directly without any kind of mapping to weight values.

Answer (score 1):

## Implement `Comparable`

Yes you can implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html). Create a method compareTo(Person obj) and then write your custom logic. You can compare alphabetically or whatever other algorithm you want - for example engineer before doctor because he makes more money :) For alphabetic comparing you can do it like that:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

@Override
public int compareTo(Person o) {
    return this.profession.compareTo(o.getProfession());

  }
  private String name;
  private String profession;
}
```

After that you just use the Collections.sort

Answer (score 1):

Add enum to your variables:

```
class Person {
   private String name;
   private String profession;
   private enum enumProffesion
    {
        Doctor, Teacher, student;
    }
}
```

After that could add function to the Person class which would give you value of the profession:

```
public int professionValue()
{
    enumProffesion enumValue= enumProffesion.valueOf(proffesion);
    switch (enumValue) {
    case Doctor: return 1; break;
    case Teacher: return 2; break;
    case student: return 3; break;
    default: return null;
    }
}
```

After that you just implement logic that will sort all Persons. For that you can help your self with this answer: [sorting integers in order lowest to highest java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787754/sorting-integers-in-order-lowest-to-highest-java)

Comment: No need of such mapping, you can compare enum instances directly. (e. g. `EnumProfession.DOCTOR.compareTo(EnumProfession.TEACHER)`) Order will be that on which values were defined.

Comment: I tried: http://pastebin.com/QnqXffmJ
And if you compare Teacher to Student you get : -1
and if you compare you also get: -1

So if you would try to sort it like I proposed in step 2you couldn't do it. But you could it a little bit diffrent.

Comment: If I try my solution: http://pastebin.com/ufbWZkVw
I get this values:
System.out.println(professionValue("Doctor"));    output: 1
System.out.println(professionValue("Teacher"));  output: 2
System.out.println(professionValue("student"));   output: 3

Comment: I like your post because no one else proposed enums, but some mapping or alphabetical sort (which became broken when `engineer` was added). But it really doesn't need such ugly mapping. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo-E-

Comment: so if you compare teacher to student by your mapping, you'll also get -1. So everything is okay.

Comment: Yes I understood your solution already before, it's probably more clean then my, but I didn't think of that before. And if I would change that I would also had to change second step of ordering elements.

Comment: Note to readers: Good idea to use enum, but the code in this Answer is needlessly complex, and does not make proper use of enum features. See [better Answer by Alex Salauyou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30101939/642706).

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your custom object using `Collection.sort` method like this,

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator(){

        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            Person p1 = (Person) o1;
            Person p2 = (Person) o2;
            return p1.getProfession().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getProfession());
        }

    });
```

To `Sort` in `reverse order` just make your `return` statement line like this,

```
p2.getProfession().compareToIgnoreCase(p1.getProfession());
```

This will directly make your `list` sorted.

Comment: by this, engineer will stand after doctor, when it needs to stand behind.

Answer (score 1):

## Enum

You can do it easily if replace `profession` field by `enum`:

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String name;
    private Profession profession;

    // by this we'll define natural ordering based on ordering
    // in which `Profession` enum values are declared
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        return this.profession.compareTo(p.profession);
    } 
}
```

And here's `Profession` enum:

```
public enum Profession {
    ENGINEER("engineer"), DOCTOR("Doctor"), TEACHER("Teacher"), STUDENT("student");
    
    private String displayName;
    
    Profession(String dn) {
        this.displayName = dn;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.displayName;
    }
}
```

If you are new to the enum facility in Java, see [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: I edited your good example code to use the `displayName` style of naming used in the JDK's classes such as [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/DayOfWeek.html#getDisplayName(java.time.format.TextStyle,java.util.Locale))

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion -

**1.** Create a new class `Profession` -

```
class Profession{

   public Profession(Integer id, String prefessionName){
      this.id=id;
      this.prefessionName=prefessionName;
   }
   Integer id;
   String professionName;

}
```

**2.** Now give Id to each `Profession` object/instance maintaining the order. For example -

```
   Profession engineer = new Profession(1, "Engineer"); //since Engineer is in first place 
   Profession doctor = new Profession(2, "Doctor"); //since Doctor is in second place
   Profession teacher = new Profession(3, "Teacher");
   Profession student = new Profession(4, "Student");
```

**3.** Now sort the `Profession` for `id` using `compareable` interface.

Comment: He probably forgot to change Doctor to 2, Teacher to 3 and Student to 4 when he was copying code...

Comment: Thanks. It was a typos, which I have just fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Add getter and setter for profession in Person class and simply use below code

```
class Person {
   private String name;
   private String profession;
   public String getProfession() {  
        return profession;  
    }  
    public void setProfession(String profession) {  
        this.profession = profession;  
    }
}


List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>(); 

Person p1 = new Person();
p1.setProfession("Engineer"); 
personList.add(p1);

Person p2 = new Person();
p2.setProfession("Doctor"); 
personList.add(p2);

Person p3 = new Person();
p3.setProfession("Teacher"); 
personList.add(p3);

Person p4 = new Person();
p4.setProfession("student"); 
personList.add(p4);


Collections.sort(personList, new Comparator() {  
@Override  
public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {  
Person p1 = (Person)obj1;  
Person p2 = (Person)obj2;  
return p1.getProfession().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getProfession());  
}  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Implement the `Comparable` interface
2. Create a `Comparator`

With the first way you can sort the collection only by the one method `compareTo` you will define

Your `Person.java`

```
class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String name;
    private String profession;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return this.profession.compareTo(o.getProfession());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getProfession() {
        return profession;
    }
}
```

Then you need to call:

```
Collections.sort(yourCollection);
```

With the second way you can sort by one or more `Comparator`, giving you the ability to compare the same collection with different criteria.

Example of two `Comparator`

```
public class PersonSortByNameComparator implements Comparator<Person>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }

}

public class PersonSortByAlphabeticalProfessionComparator implements Comparator<Person>{

    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getProfession().compareTo(p2.getProfession());
    }

}
```

Or this one you need:

```
public class PersonSortByProfessionComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        if(p1.getProfession().equalsIgnoreCase(p2.getProfession())
            return 0;
        if(p1.getProfession().equalsIgnoreCase("student")
            return -1;
        if(p1.getProfession().equalsIgnoreCase("engineer")
            return 1;
        if(p1.getProfession().equalsIgnoreCase("doctor")
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

And then call one of them:

```
Collections.sort(yourCollection, new PersonSortByNameComparator());
```

[This blog article](http://www.java2blog.com/2013/02/difference-between-comparator-and.html) is really good written and you can some examples