# Finding the 10 highest frequencies in a randomized array-Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, frequency

The project description is to create an array of 1000 randomized numbers from 1-50 and to display the 10 highest numbers by frequency. I cut down the numbers in my code for easier testing.

I have created the array with randomized numbers and displayed how many times each number occurred.

I am having trouble figuring out how to sort the numbers from  highest highest to lowest.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;  //import random class and arrays


class MaxArray{
   public static void main(String[]args){

      Random rand = new Random(1);  //create random object and sets seed to one

      int[] randArray = new int [51];
      int[] newArray = new int[51];

      for(int i = 0; i < randArray.length; i++){
         randArray[i] = rand.nextInt(50) + 1; // returns a single random integer between 1 and 50
         }
      Arrays.sort(randArray);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randArray));

      for(int j = 0; j < randArray.length; j++){
         newArray[randArray[j]] += 1;     
         }
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));

      for(int k = 0; k < newArray.length; k++){
         System.out.println("Number " + k + " occurred " + newArray[k] + " times");
         }    
   }// end main
}//end class
```

Comment: If you are just looking to sort the integers, implement this answer in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787754/sorting-integers-in-order-lowest-to-highest-java?lq=1

Comment: "Having trouble" does not provide enough information to help. please see the SO FAQ regarding how to ask questions: at a bare minimum you should take the time to describe, precisely as possible, the "trouble".

Comment: Why would you need to sort your numbers from highest to lowest?

Comment: FYI, your 2nd for-loop (which contains `newArray[randArray[j]] += 1; ` ) is already doing the sorting for your `randArray`, we call it bucket sort.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

This is how you get from highest to lowest

```
for (int i = randArray.length-1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        System.out.print(randArray[i]+" ");

}
```

and this is how you find 10 highest numbers:

```
 int CheckingDublicate = 0, count = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= randArray.length; i++){

        if(count<=10{
            if(CheckingDublicate!=randArray[randArray.length-i])
            {
                //Ignoring if dublicate
                System.out.print(randArray[randArray.length-i]+" ");
                CheckingDublicate = randArray[randArray.length-i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        else
            break;
    }
```

Comment: the code that "sort" did nothing related to sorting.  The next part doing "find 10 highest" suffers from a  lot of problem: wrong syntax, bad naming convention, wrong logic.

Comment: Because it is just wrong, and I have given the problems in my previous comment.  It is probably not completely your responsibility coz the original question was poorly asked.

Comment: Well, first, your code are not correct, syntax-wise and logic-wise. Second, your description is wrong (e.g. "This is how you sort..." but the code has nothing to do with sorting).   Third, you are not even answering the question: he was asking for highest frequency while your code is just finding highest numeric values.  So it is not only OP's problem either.